# TypeScript Global Type Defintions

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

My JavaScript code makes heavy use of globals for jQuery widgets.

Right now I am declaring type definitions in .d.ts files which I store in a customTypes directory.

Is there a way to declare these type definitions within the jQuery widget files themselves and therefore not have two files to modify everytime I need to modify the widget.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript does not know about Typescript type definitions. You would have to write your jQuery widgets with Typescript. Then you can set a flag (`-d or --declaration`) in your typescript compiler options to create a type definition file. That way you would not have to update the definitions every time you change the code.

Comment: I mean my jQuery widgets are now. ts files (Im porting JS to TS) so could I write definitions in there?

Comment: If your jQuery widgets are in Typescript, then you have no problem. Just add the `-d` flag o your compiler options and the TypeScript compiler will create the declaration files for you.